# queries in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have to fetch the top 20 rows using this query and the like clause  is not working.  Can anybody tell me why / help me find a solution?

```
var zipcodes = (from results in db1.ZipCodes1 
                                 where  results.CityType == "D" && results.ZIPCode like '%ZC %'
                                 select new Ajaxresults 
                {
                   ZIPCode= results.ZIPCode,
                   CityName = results.CityName,
                   StateAbbr = results.StateAbbr,
                   StateName = results.StateName
                }).GroupBy(o => o.ZIPCode);
```

Comment: use `results.ZIPCode.Contains("ZC ")` in place of like.

Comment: i have to select top 20 rows in above query

Comment: @aligray put your answer in the 'Your Answer' box, rather than as a comment.

Comment: Then you'll need to add `.Take(20);` to a suitable part of your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select the top 20 rows, you should use the LINQ `Take` operator

```
var zipcodes = (from results in db1.ZipCodes1
   ...
   ).Take(20);
```

Answer (score 4):

Code should look like this:

```
var zipcodes = (from results in db1.ZipCodes1 
                where  results.CityType == "D" && results.ZIPCode.Contains("ZC ")
                select new Ajaxresults 
                {
                   ZIPCode= results.ZIPCode,
                   CityName = results.CityName,
                   StateAbbr = results.StateAbbr,
                   StateName = results.StateName
                }).GroupBy(o => o.ZIPCode).Take(20);
```

Comment: i have to make a view model according to this result how can i make this

Comment: in your view model class, create a Zipcodes Property of Type IEnumerable<AjaxResults>.

Answer (score 1):

The String.Contains method will be translated to the corresponding SQL LIKE operator. You could change your query to something like that:

```
var zipcodes = (from results in db1.ZipCodes1 
                             where results.CityType == "D" 
                                && results.ZIPCode.Contains("ZC ")
                             select new Ajaxresults 
            {
               ZIPCode= results.ZIPCode,
               CityName = results.CityName,
               StateAbbr = results.StateAbbr,
               StateName = results.StateName
            }).GroupBy(o => o.ZIPCode);
```